# $event in in ng-repeat does not fire correctly every time

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

i have a list generated by ng-repeat lookgin like this:

```
<li ng-repeat='task in tasksList | filter: projectFilter' class="list-element">
    <a id='task-{{$index}}' ng-click="taskDetails($event)">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="name-and-date">
          <span class="task-name">{{task.name}}</span> <span class="due-date">{{task.displayDate}}</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="additional-info">
          <span>{{task.project}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='task-{{$index}}-details'  class="details">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </a> 
</li>
```

and the definition for the `taskDetails` in view's controller:

```
$scope.taskDetails = function($event) {
    var showDetails = document.getElementById($event.target.id + '-details');
    showDetails.style.display = 'block';
};
```

For some reason, the function does not catch the id of the `<a>` element every time, hence it works on some rowa of list, while on the other rows I get an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Can anybody explain why it happens like that?

Regards

Comment: why not just pass the `$index` since that is what you are looking for anyway?

Comment: Approach is all wrong looking for dom nodes when you can simply use `ng-show` and your data model to manage it

Comment: +1 to charlieftl. The template should just have `ng-click="task.detailed = true"` and `<div class="details" ng-if="task.detailed">`. The model is the source of truth. Not the DOM.

Comment: @charlietfl @JB Nizet I am storing task object in database, and I do not see a point to store additional value `task.detailed`. Is it possible to add this value to the object after it was received from database?

Comment: @castellan9168 it doesn't even need to be part of the `task` object if it is simply a user interface like "read more/less" or "show/hide details". Since ng-repeat creates a child scope it could even be a simple variable that doesn't even exist in controller...depending on behavior expected and if it needs to persist

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the advice. I have modified it to have the ability to open / close details of the task like this `ng-click="show.detailed == true ? show.detailed = false : show.detailed = true"`. Is there any way to write it more neatly?
How to change the default value of `task.detailed` from `false` to `true`

Comment: can simplify to `ng-click="show.detailed = !show.detailed"`. If you want to use task object use it instead of `show` object and you can also use inverse `ng-hide` instead of `ng-show`